# How to use default argument values, when templating over a function?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to be able to wrap a function call with some arbitrary 'prefix' and 'postfix' code, like so:

```
template <typename Function, typename ... Args>
void WrappedCall(Function f, Args ... args)
{
    //Do something before the call...

    f(args...);

    //Do something after the call...
}

void Function(int def_val = 0)
{

}
```

Using this, submitting all arguments explicitly works perfectly well:

```
WrappedCall(Function, 0);
```

But attempting to make use of the default value fails ('too few arguments to function f(args...)'):

```
WrappedCall(Function);
```

How can I work around this? The structure of the code achieving this behavior can be completely different to the example I've written, but I would like, if possible, to maintain the simple calling pattern, as I want to use this on functions from some libraries that can have really long signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression:

```
WrappedCall([](){Function();} );
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qocs3ncq)

---

Default arguments are actually rather limited. This fails for the same reason:

```
void(*f)(int) = Function;
f();   // error too few arguments :/
```

Somehow you need to turn `Function` into a callable whose type allows to be called without arguments. And the lambda achieves that.

---

If your `Function` has more non-defaulted arguments this works as well:

```
template <typename Function, typename ... Args>
void WrappedCall(Function f, Args ... args)
{
    //Do something before the call...

    f(args...);

    //Do something after the call...
}

void Function(int x,double y, float z,int def_val = 0)
{

}

int main() {
    WrappedCall([](auto&&...args){Function(args...);},0,0.0,0.0);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hns1n5GeW)

---

PS: I didn't consider perfect forwarding here, as it is also missing from your code, but you should definitely read about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This indeed works, but is somewhat inconvenient syntactically, and requires passing variables to the lambda capture list. Is is somehow possible to get this kind of behaviour on the template side of things?

Comment: "and requires passing variables to the lambda capture list." no it doesnt. I think you mean it requires declaring the lambda to take the non-defaulted arguments, right?

Comment: Yes, You are exactly right. Sorry for the confusion. Still, this leads to quite heavy syntax when dealing with functions of long signatures, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @XenophiliusMildrententus no it does not. Frankly it is difficult when you talk about inconvenience or "long signatures" when this is only what you anticipate, but I cannot know what you mean exactly. I hope I addressed your concerns in my edit. If not you should show an example of what you mean

Comment: @XenophiliusMildrententus please read the answer carefully (reload the page?). I did add an example where `Function` has an additional `int` argument. The lambda needs no change when `Function` has arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @XenophiliusMildrententus and i extended the example to a "really long signature"

Comment: I missed one of your edits, I refreshed now. Ok i see using auto&& ... in lambda expression solves the issue, so I'm marking this as solved. Thank You again and sorry if I was being too nebulous, maybe I should have used a concrete use case example instead of trying to contrive a minimal code.